# How to know which website ask for an external image served by php?

Tags: php, api, authorization, referrer

I have a PHP file serving images. It ask for an "api key" (to limit the access) and a string.
Then it generate a PNG image and return it.

To access the image:

```
<img src="http://www.myserver.com/mypage.php?api=APIKEY&text=some-text-here" alt=""/>
```

This image will be called from third party's website.

I need to know if the website related to the api key is the same as the one asking for the image.

I can grab the referrer but I know sometimes it can be empty.

How can I verify this information? Is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `Referer` header is the only thing you can use for this.  Yes, it can be unreliable, and is definitely easily spoofed.  But, it will provide some protection for you.

Comment: Okay, thanks Brad for the info. Will it be okay to deny access to the requests asking for the image if there's no referer?

Comment: @JeremyDicaire, Generally, yes.  This is commonly done to prevent hot-linking image files.  I can't think of a browser off the top of my head that doesn't send the `Referer` header for images on a page.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you so much for this helpful information :)